# Use Regex to extract multiple {tag} from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex

I have email template that look like that:

```
Dear {user.firstName},<br><br> Thank you for buying {item} with us. <br><br>
Your Order ID is : <b> {{orderId}} </b>. <br><br>
Thank again for supporting us.
```

Below is the example of what i trying to extract from the paragraph:

1) The thing inside {} from a paragraph

```
user.firstName // from {user.firstName}
item // from {item}
orderId // from {{orderId}}
```

2) Entire {} including the thing inside from a paragraph

```
{user.firstName} // from {user.firstName}
{item} // from {item}
{orderId} // from {{orderId}}
```

For (1), I tried with `/{(.*)}/g` or `/({)(.*)(})/g` but it will still select entire {{tag}}.

Below is what i have tried for (2):

```
/({([a-z])\w+})|({([a-z])+})|({([A-Z])\w+})|({([A-Z])+})|({[0-9]+})/g
```

It can cater most of criteria, except if there is a/multiple dot in the {tag}.

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: What about trying something like ``({([\w\.]*)})`` ?

Comment: This should work `(?<=\{).+?(?=\})` Check here https://regex101.com/r/mTWiSW/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the following regexp:

`({([\w\.]*)})`

There your matches would have two capture groups:

1. The full match, with your braces, like `{user.firstName}`
2. Whatever is inside the brances, like `user.firstName`

You can also check that expression here https://regex101.com/r/eXKJzs/1/

Comment: OP should note this will work only if we explicitly allow only one or two brackets, since [regular expression can't handle more complex nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/)

Comment: @J.Pichardo Thanks for replying. As tested, it work with my question (2), in a very simple way. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2 : based on comments received from @melpomene

```js
var reg = /{([\w(.*\w)*]+)}/g;

var string = "{x}Dear {user.firstName},<br><br> Thank you for buying {item} with us. <br><br>Your Order ID is : <b> {{orderId}} </b>. <br><br> Thank again for supporting us.";

var result = null;
while(result = reg.exec(string))
    console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: Your code fails horribly if you add a single-letter tag at the beginning of `string`: `"{x} Dear {user.firstName}, ..."`

Comment: @melpomene it will match content inside `{` and `}` starting from `{` to first occurrence of `}`. `(?=})` means until first positive lookahead, same as `break` in looping.

Comment: You already have a fixed `}` in your regex. `(?=})}` is redundant.

Comment: @melpomene can you please check now? I've edited code and added example.

Comment: `[\d\w]` is just `\w`. `\w` already includes digits. `[.*]` is nonsensical here. It matches either a literal `.` or a literal `*`.

Comment: If you want to match everything up to the next `}`, why not just do `{([^}]+)}`? What's this obsession with `+?`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172274/discussion-between-vivek-and-melpomene).